# setattr strange behaviour when there is class inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an issue with setattr when using it in inheritance with classes and decorators.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import inspect

def make_class_decorator(function_decorator):
  def class_decorator(cls):
    for attr_name in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.isroutine):
      attr_name = attr_name[0]
      if str(attr_name).startswith('__') and str(attr_name).endswith('__'): continue
      attr_value = getattr(cls, str(attr_name))
      setattr(cls, attr_name, function_decorator(cls, attr_value))

    return cls
  return class_decorator

@make_class_decorator
def auto_debug_logging(cls, called_function):
  def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
    print('wrapped')
    return called_function(*args, **kwargs)

  wrapped.__name__ = called_function.__name__
  return wrapped

def xclassmethod(called_function):
  def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
    print('wrappedx: ' + called_function.__name__)
    return builtins.classmethod(called_function(*args, **kwargs))

  return wrapped

class X:
  @xclassmethod
  def get_i(cls):
    cls._inst = cls()
    return cls._inst

@auto_debug_logging
class A(X):
  pass

@auto_debug_logging
class B(A):
  def test(self):
    print('test')

B.get_i().test()
```

Example code shows that all functions are wrapped, and prints "wrapped" before actual call. However, when I call B.get_i().test I'm getting following error:
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'test'

It seems that setattr somehow sets the original B class to A, as when I comment out that the issue disappears.

Comment: The problem is that your `@auto_debug_logging` decorator creates a bound method. When you do `getattr(cls, str(attr_name))` with `get_i`, that creates a bound method where the `A` class is baked in as the value for the `cls` parameter. You can avoid that by replacing the `getattr(cls, str(attr_name))` with `inspect.getattr_static(cls, attr_name)`, but then you'll have other problems...

Comment: What are problems do you refer?

Comment: You'll end up trying to decorate a `classmethod` object, which isn't callable. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: So I cannot log get_instance (and other classmethod) calls, right? Any solution for that?

Comment: Well, you could decorate the underlying function and then turn the decorated function into a classmethod.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Can you attach an example code? I have tried the following (added to the question) but not working as it expecting a cls attribute.